# django "makemigrations" problem not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
08:41 ~/myapk $ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chaxim/myapk/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/chaxim/myapk/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 228, in create
    if not issubclass(app_config_class, AppConfig):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

everytime i tried to make migrations it shows same thing, i even tried export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yoursite.settings
command but no result.

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import profile

# Register your models here.


admin.site.register(profile)
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProfilesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'profiles'

    def ready(self):
        import profiles.signals
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    business_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    #location =
    follow_BNS = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='othe_BNS',blank=True)
    D_p = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pic')
    #slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.business_name},{self.phone_num}'
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import profile
from django.conf import settings


settings.configure()

settings.configure()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def post_save_create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print('sender', sender)
    print('instance', instance)
    if created:
        profile.objects.created(user=instance)
```

settings

```
"""
Django settings for myapk project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-d*e6ejr7t^0a-9uwh70$789_vyrzwxgkapm-d4=pa_2vg0s_x6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'share',
    'hitcount',
    'post',
    'profiles',
    'location',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapk.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # this is to load the html file from templates folder
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'template'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapk.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# default static files settings for PythonAnywhere.
# see https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles for more info
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/chaxim/myapk/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/chaxim/myapk/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

this is my code so far i haven't created any view yet nor urls, but I keep getting the error

i also tried running DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yoursite.settings command but nothing works

Comment: please show us your code to help you where the issue happens

Answer (score 1):

did you include in your settings.py
'yourapp'

Comment: i have include it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: my question is how can i resolve this problem

Comment: I have exatcly the same problem : could you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74911506/django-3-2typeerror-issubclass-arg-1-must-be-a-class